# Please clarify on the relation between Xen, VirtualBox, Sun VM and Oracle VM

Tags: virtualization, xen, virtualbox

Please clarify on the relation between xen, VirtualBox, Sun vm and Oracle vm

- Which products still exist after Oracle acquired Sun?
- which of the products that still exists are derived from xen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sun VM = Virtualbox. Hardware assisted virtualization. Very much like VMWare but with a lot of Open Source. Very good solution for desktop uses.

Xen = NOT a linux kernel patch set. This is utterly wrong. Xen is a full-blown hypervisor. It sits below the Linux/Unix kernel. The kernel of the OS running atop can be patched to work with Xen which allows native speed for VMs. It is an open source projet from which the Citrix version was derived after they bought the trademark. Xen kernel patches are now integrated into mainstream Linux kernel (called pvops).

VirtualBox = See Sun VM.

Oracle VM = Xen packaged and adapted by Oracle.

Sun xVM = Xen adaptation to OpenSolaris. No plans to have it removed... It is even in [Oracle's roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/us/sun/sun-products-map-075562.html).

All are here to stay. Oracle VM is Xen for Linux and Sun xVM is Xen for OpenSolaris.